# Get data from time range in facebook ads api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

How to get data from the time range `2020-05-06 to 2020-06-06`?
This query does not work:

`<ACC_ID>/ads?time_range={'since':'2020-05-06','until':'2020-06-06'}&fields=insights{cpc,spend}`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [Insights Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights) that support filtering, sorting and useful aggregation level, in your case, should be something like:

```
act_XXX/insights?level=ad&fields=cpc,spend&time_range={'since':'2020-05-06','until':'2020-06-06'}
```

Other info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/)

Comment: But it should work as in Facebook business manager. I mean when we choose for example date 'since':'2020-05-06','until':'2020-06-06', it should show all ads but with results from this period.

Comment: I don't know if the edge you are using suppor the filter option. Try using the `filtering`  params. I will take a look tomorrow

Comment: Awesome, the edge <ACC_ID>/ads supports filtering, but I do not know why my query: `<ACC_ID>/ads?time_range={'since':'2020-05-06','until':'2020-06-06'}&fields=insights{cpc,spend}` does not work

Comment: Waiting for your response.